# Django custom AppConfig breaks the project

Tags: django, django-admin, django-apps

I've got a bare-bones demonstration Django project created with Django 2.2.  The structure looks like:

```sh
my_project/
├── db.sqlite3
├── my_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── my_project
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── requirements.txt
```

This started as a tiny issue: "my_app" was showing up in the Django admin as "MY_APP" (with an underscore). The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) say that you can make this prettier by defining a custom app config that subclasses "django.apps.AppConfig", and that typically this subclass would be defined in (using my example) "my_app/apps.py".  In fact, using `manage.py startapp my_app` even generates this for you:

```py
# my_app/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'
```

The docs also say to "put the dotted path to that subclass in INSTALLED_APPS".  Another approach is to set the `default_app_config` variable in your app's "__init__.py", but that "New applications should avoid default_app_config. Instead they should require the dotted path to the appropriate AppConfig subclass to be configured explicitly in INSTALLED_APPS."

However, if I do add the path to the custom app config into `INSTALLED_APPS` like this:

```py
# settings.py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'                                                                                                                                                                            
]
...
```

the project immediately crashes with "LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'."

The error traces back to the reference to `admin.site.urls` in the project's root "urls.py" (line 6 below):

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_app/', include('my_app.urls', namespace='my_app'))
]
```

In conclusion, adding the path to the "apps" module created by "startapp" -- even without 
 making any changes to that module -- crashes the project. OTOH if I go against the docs' advice and define `default_app_config` in "my_app/**init**.py", *that* does work.

This seems very basic, but Googling it is turning up nothing, which usually means I'm making some fundamental error that I don't realize.  Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Not sure it's the problem, but you definitely shouldn't include the app in INSTALLED_APPS twice. Remove the `'my_app'` version.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! But... is this obvious? I've seen other projects with `INSTALLED_APPS` like `['some_app', 'some_app.plugins.plugin1', 'some_app.plugins.plugin2']` and so on. Not under Django 2.2 though. Did something change?

Comment: But that's not the same thing. Those are separate apps under "some_app.plugins".

Comment: I guess I don't understand what makes something a "separate app" vs. just another module inside an app. Why does `INSTALLED_APPS=['some_app', 'some_app.apps.MyAppConfig']` cause an error but the hypothetical examples in my previous comment do not? Both cases just seem like directories with python modules inside.  I get that in the first case the path is drilling down inside the module to import a specific class, but that's not what makes the difference, is it?